# Does flashing stock ROM via Odin delete phone data?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, stock-android, odin

So my Galaxy S6 is stuck in a boot loop and I've literally tried EVERYTHING already and nothing will solve the problem. Safe mode won't work, clearing the cache partition won't work and USB Debugging was turned off so adb wasn't seeing my device either. I also tried Kies and Smart Switch. I am convinced my phone is soft bricked and I need to recover some **very** important pictures and files from it. At this point my last hope is to flash the stock ROM via Odin and I saw that some people have said that they have successfully done this without losing any of their data. Is this possible? If so how do I go about doing it properly? If you can give me a step by step of what settings to use in Odin to not lose my data I would greatly appreciate it!!

Thanks for any help!

Phone is not rooted and 100% stock. Recovery and Download screens are working.

Phone: T-mobile Galaxy S6 with Lollipop

Comment: Flash a custom recovery from download mode and recovery data by booting into that recovery.

Comment: @Firelord I've read that to download a custom recovery it's recommended to factory reset your phone first. Can I avoid this step?

Comment: No, that's incorrect info. Mind sharing the link (where you read it) with us?

Comment: Yes it does delete your phone. But as @Firelord said, you don't need to factory reset.

Comment: Not sure where it was saw it couple of days ago on an XDA forum can't find it again. @SarpSTA What deletes my phone?

Comment: Flashing stock ROM. It overwrites everything in your phone.

Comment: @SarpSTA How sure are you of that? Because I saw a video of someone doing it and they kept all their data. It's starting to get confusing with multiple conflicting reports saying it worked/didn't work for them :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure. A stock ROM with .kdz extension includes every partition of the phone to replace the recent ones. Can you link me to the video?

Comment: @SarpSTA https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOxeNAK6-aI

Comment: @SarpSTA Update, I went ahead and flashed the stock ROM and it's still in a bootloop... Have no idea what happened to my files but at this point it's quite stressful

Comment: @Nabjav Can you provide me with the link of topic or page you found the stock rom on?

Comment: @SarpSTA From Sammobile which I know to be reliable: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-G920T/

Comment: @Nabjav It is reliable. What wasn't is my knowledge obviously pretty much to my shame. It turns out that data and cache partitions are created during the first boot and therefore are not included in the `.kdz`. Therefore your recent cache and data are not overwritten or wiped. If your problem persists even after flashing stock ROM it means that cause of bootloop is originating from data partition. You need to wipe it clean to fix the bootloop.

Comment: @SarpSTA Yes at this point I figured that. Quite unfortunate but chances are looking pretty slim of data recovery, oh well. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: @Nabjav I think saving images might still be possible pretty much though.

Comment: @TechRando I am currently going through exactly same situation. My Samsung Galaxy A6+ got stuck while upgrading OS and now it stucks at samsung logo when booting. Recovery and Download screens are working. Did you manage to recover data by flashing stock? Would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: @Atul Unfortunately, I was not able to recover the data. Wish I could be of more help

Answer (score -4):

None of your internal storage files i.e. **Photos, Music, Videos, Docs etc**., will not be removed until you do a **repartition of the device** using Odin. Your phone will be restored to perfect condition; just that all your personal information will be gone such as contacts that were on the phone storage and apps.

***But I'm not responsible if anything goes wrong. Do it at your own risk.***

**OR**

You can **flash a custom recovery** using Odin and use the MTP feature of the recovery and move the required files (which I assume would be safer).

Comment: That double negation makes this answer really really fuzzy. So what _does_ the statement entail: the files do or do not get removed?

Comment: @0xC0000022L rightly pointed out the confusion in understanding the answer. Down voted for this reason. Please correct and ping me for clean up and reversing down vote. Thanks

Comment: Any Samsung expert - if you can suggest edits to improve this answer, please discuss in chat before doing that. Thanks