# Correct TWRP Build for Samsung J7 (SM-J727U)

Tags: samsung, twrp

I have a boot loop issue similar to [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137067/does-flashing-stock-rom-via-odin-delete-phone-data), and would like to try to flash TWRP on to my device with Odin. The TWRP site has four variations of the J7. I'm pretty sure that based on this [specs data](http://phonedb.net/index.php?m=device&id=12997&c=samsung_sm-j727u_galaxy_j7_2017_lte-a__samsung_j727) I have an Exynos processor, which narrows it down to two TWRP options:

**1. Samsung Galaxy J7 (2016 Exynos) (j7xelte)** [TWRP page](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxyj72016exynos.html)
This one has a link to [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7/samsung-galaxy-j7-2016-exynos-7870-guides-development-and-mods/recovery-official-twrp-j7xelte-galaxy-t3437659) that indicates it is only for various SM-J710xx models.

**2. Samsung Galaxy J7 Exynos SM-J700 (j7elte)** [TWRP page](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxyj7exynos.html)
The changelog on that one references `exynos7580` which doesn't match the processor number specified on that specs link I found for my phone.

My current recovery screen shows:

```
Android Recovery
samsung/j7popelteue/j7popelteue
7.0/NRD90M/J727UUEU3ARB1
```

Does anyone know what the correct TWRP build would be for this model of phone?

Comment: Neither. There simply is none for your device (not even unofficial).

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. Thank you for responding though @andy. Any other methods of getting out of boot loop and recovering data?

Comment: here is the solution , this link https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7/development/recovery-twrp-3-1-1-x-galaxy-j727p-t3692663 , have the codename as you shown. and you model is not J727U, it is J727P.

Comment: My model is J727P? The message from my recovery has 'J727U', and the label under my battery says "Model: SM-J727U"

Comment: Thank you for your help @Mukund - what is the codename you are referring to?

Comment: @Mukund NO - J727P is the Sprint variant with Qualcomm chips. Won't work like that.